# Why do I get the server error "Error: HTMLElement is not defined" when I'm trying to import a Shadcn Badge with a common imports index.ts file?

Tags: html, reactjs, next.js, import, shadcnui

I have a Next 14 application in which I am using Shadcn components on the UI. One of these components is the **Badge** component that I have left untouched.

I can import the Badge component, use it on pages, use it within my other components, and at no point am I facing any issue with that. However, while organizing the imports in my project, I created an `index.ts` file as shown below:

```
export { default as ErrorMessage } from "./ErrorMessage";
export { default as IssueStatusBadge } from "./IssueStatusBadge";
export { default as LabelWithErrorMessage } from "./LabelWithErrorMessage";
export { default as Loader } from "./Loader";
export { default as Skeleton } from "./Skeleton";
```

All of these components share the same folder and can be freely imported and used anywhere I want to in the project. For example:

```
import { Loader, LabelWithErrorMessage } from "@/app/components";
```

The issue arises when I try to use the **IssueStatusBadge** component. Here's the code for the **IssueStatusBadge**.

```
import { Badge } from "@/components/ui/badge";
import { Status } from "@prisma/client";

const statusMap: Record<Status, { label: string; bgClass: string }> = {
  OPEN: { label: "Open", bgClass: "bg-red-600" },
  IN_PROGRESS: { label: "In Progress", bgClass: "bg-indigo-600" },
  CLOSED: { label: "Closed", bgClass: "bg-emerald-600" },
};

const IssueStatusBadge = ({ status }: { status: Status }) => {
  return (
    <Badge className={statusMap[status].bgClass}>
      {statusMap[status].label}
    </Badge>
  );
};

export default IssueStatusBadge;
```

If I import this component with the same approach, I get the server error, *"Error: HTMLElement is not defined"*.

```
import IssueStatusBadge from "@/app/components/IssueStatusBadge"; // Works!
import { IssueStatusBadge } from "@/app/components"; // throws Error!
```

Why is that? I have checked the Shadcn component and it's returning just a **div** element with some styling configurations.

I have continued to use Shadcn imports without using any common `index.ts` file and it works for now. I am just curious about why the other approach didn't work for Shadcn components as to my eyes, it looks like it should have worked anyway. Any information to help me understand this behavior would be much appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: As it is a server error, have you try adding "use client" at the top of your index.ts file?

Comment: @PinalTilva While that is possible, I have prisma client logic on the component where I am trying to import the status badge component. So it needs to be on the server side. I know I can extract the portion where I use the badge and create a client side component separately for it. But that makes the whole import organisation process redundant as it's better to import it directly anyway. I just don't understand why the error gets thrown and how best to deal with it without having to take alternate routes for dealing with technical approaches.